# How can I keep a reference to something that gets moved?

Tags: c++, move, rapidjson

I have something as the following using rapidjson

```
rapidjson::Value parent;
parent.SetObject();

rapidjson::Value child;
child.SetObject();

parent.AddMember("child", child, document.GetAllocator());
```

The problem is when I call `parent.AddMember()`, the library nullifies my `child` variable because rapidjson uses move semantics.

How can I still keep a reference to the `child` value when it gets moved?

Ideally, I'd like to keep a reference to the `child` node so that I can modify it later, without having to go find it in the JSON tree.

Comment: You could read books about garbage collection, e.g. https://gchandbook.org/

Comment: What does addmember return? I tried searching the documentation but couldn't find it

Comment: @linuxfever `*this` - that is, a reference to `parent`

Comment: Seems like what you want is not a reference to a `Value` but rather a reference to the Value's internal state (i.e. to whatever internal data-object it is that gets moved from one `Value` object to another as methods like `AddMember()` get called).  Dunno if that's supported by the rapidjson API, though.

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to rapidjson:

When you have a reference to an object `child`, and the resource owned by `child` is transferred to another object by moving, the reference to `child` is still valid, but the referred object is no longer the one that owns the resource.

You cannot make the original reference variable to refer to the other object. But you could use a pointer or a reference wrapper instead, if you change the value of the pointer when the pointed object is moved.

---

I'm not familiar with rapidjson, but with a brief browsing of documentation, you could at least use `parent.FindMember` to get a reference to the newly created member, and update the pointer to that.